# how can I compare two columns of strings together

Tags: r

I have two df, one is df1

```
df1<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 
8L), .Label = c("A0A061ACH4;Q95Q10;Q9U1W6", "A0A061ACL3;Q965I6;O76618", 
"A0A061ACR1;Q2XN02;F5GUA3;Q22498", "A0A061AJJ3;A0A061AEA8", "A0A061AL01", 
"C1P641", "H2FLH3;H2FLH2;A0A061ACT3;A0A061AE24;Q23551-2;Q23551;Q23551-4;Q23551-3;Q23551-5", 
"Q22501;A0A061AE05", "Q86CZ7"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

and the other is df2

```
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 
7L), .Label = c("A0A061ACH4;Q95Q10;Q9U1W6", "A0A061ACL3;Q965I6;O76618", 
"A0A061ACR1;Q2XN02;F5GUA3;Q22498", "A0A061AJJ3;A0A061AEA8", "A0A061AL01", 
"H2FLH3;H2FLH2;A0A061ACT3;A0A061AE24;Q23551-2;Q23551;Q23551-4;Q23551-3;Q23551-5", 
"Q22501;A0A061AE05", "Q27GQ4", "Q86CZ7"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want to compare these two from each other line by line.
which line is similar from df1 to df2 and vice versa

then make an output with all unique lines from both df1 and df2 (means all lines from those two df in one new df)

Then in front of those lines that we don't have in df1 but we have in df2 , we mention a zero and the same for df2.

an expected output can be like below

```
output<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 
10L, 11L, 9L), .Label = c("", "A0A061ACH4;Q95Q10;Q9U1W6", "A0A061ACL3;Q965I6;O76618", 
"A0A061ACR1;Q2XN02;F5GUA3;Q22498", "A0A061AJJ3;A0A061AEA8", "A0A061AL01", 
"C1P641", "H2FLH3;H2FLH2;A0A061ACT3;A0A061AE24;Q23551-2;Q23551;Q23551-4;Q23551-3;Q23551-5", 
"Q22501;A0A061AE05", "Q27GQ4", "Q86CZ7"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "0", "df1"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", 
    "df2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Here `Q27GQ4` does not exist in df1 but exist in df2, so in the column of df1 in the output we mention zero 
Here `C1P641`exist in df1 but not in df2 so in the column of df2 in the output we mention zero.

I would appreciate any help since I am very new in R and I could not figure it out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
op <- merge(df1,df2, 
      all.x = TRUE,
      all.y = TRUE) 

op$df1 <- 1*(op$V1 %in% df1$V1)

op$df2 <- 1*(op$V1 %in% df2$V1)

> op
                                                                               V1 df1 df2
1                                                        A0A061ACH4;Q95Q10;Q9U1W6   1   1
2                                                        A0A061ACL3;Q965I6;O76618   1   1
3                                                 A0A061ACR1;Q2XN02;F5GUA3;Q22498   1   1
4                                                           A0A061AJJ3;A0A061AEA8   1   1
5                                                                      A0A061AL01   1   1
6                                                                          C1P641   1   0
7  H2FLH3;H2FLH2;A0A061ACT3;A0A061AE24;Q23551-2;Q23551;Q23551-4;Q23551-3;Q23551-5   1   1
8                                                               Q22501;A0A061AE05   1   1
9                                                                          Q86CZ7   1   1
10                                                                         Q27GQ4   0   1
```

OR

```
library(dplyr)

op <- merge(df1,df2, 
             all.x = TRUE,
             all.y = TRUE) %>% 
        mutate(df1=1*(V1 %in% df1$V1),
               df2=1*(V1 %in% df2$V1))
```

**And here are the answers for your extra questions:**

-know how many lines from df1 and df2 are similar?

```
sum(df1$V1 %in% df2$V1)
```

-how many of df1 exist which don't exist in df2?

```
sum(!(df1$V1 %in% df2$V1))
```

-how many of df2 exist which don't exist in df1?

```
sum(!(df2$V1 %in% df1$V1))
```

Comment: Or `op <- merge(data.frame(df1,V2="",stringsAsFactors=FALSE),data.frame(df2,V3="",stringsAsFactors=FALSE),all=TRUE)`. Then replace `NA` with `op[is.na(op] <- 0`. This avoids having to do the matches using `%in%` afterwards.

Comment: @aichao thanks  is it possible to know how many lines from df1 and df2 are similar ? and how many of df1 exist which don't exist in df2 and vice versa?

Comment: -know how many lines from df1 and df2 are similar ?
`sum(df1$V1 %in% df2$V1)`

-how many of df1 exist which don't exist in df2?
`sum(!(df1$V1 %in% df2$V1))`

--how many of df2 exist which don't exist in df1?
`sum(!(df2$V1 %in% df1$V1))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
vals <- unique(c(as.character(df1$V1), as.character(df2$V1)))
data.frame(vals, df1=is.na(match(vals, df1$V1)), df2=is.na(match(vals, df2$V1)))
#                                                                              vals   df1   df2
# 1                                                        A0A061ACH4;Q95Q10;Q9U1W6 FALSE FALSE
# 2                                                        A0A061ACL3;Q965I6;O76618 FALSE FALSE
# 3                                                 A0A061ACR1;Q2XN02;F5GUA3;Q22498 FALSE FALSE
# 4  H2FLH3;H2FLH2;A0A061ACT3;A0A061AE24;Q23551-2;Q23551;Q23551-4;Q23551-3;Q23551-5 FALSE FALSE
# 5                                                                      A0A061AL01 FALSE FALSE
# 6                                                                          C1P641 FALSE  TRUE
# 7                                                           A0A061AJJ3;A0A061AEA8 FALSE FALSE
# 8                                                                          Q86CZ7 FALSE FALSE
# 9                                                               Q22501;A0A061AE05 FALSE FALSE
# 10                                                                         Q27GQ4  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: thanks  is it possible to know how many lines from df1 and df2 are similar ? and how many of df1 exist which don't exist in df2 and vice versa?